# Explain plan not showing most columns

Tags: oracle, tuning

I am running an explain plan for a query and it only returns the following columns:

```
explain plan for SELECT ....

SET LINESIZE 130
SET PAGESIZE 0
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

Plan hash value: 3706016447

------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                         | Name       |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                  |            |
|*  1 |  FILTER                                           |            |
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                              |            |
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                                   |            |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                                  |            |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                                 |            |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS                                |            |
....
```

Why? if I try another simple query it works fine...

```
SQL>  explain plan for select * from dba_users;

Explained.

    SET LINESIZE 130
    SET PAGESIZE 0
    SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);
Plan hash value: 2145154934

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name                    | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |                         |   137 | 37949 |    37   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS               |                         |   137 | 37949 |    37   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   HASH JOIN                 |                         |    41 | 10414 |    24   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL        | TS$                     |     8 |    88 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    HASH JOIN                |                         |    41 |  9963 |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL       | TS$                     |     8 |    88 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

**UPDATE**: this seems to happen because I am using the `/*+ RULE*/` hint, how to explain with RULE hint? I need to compare it with the `/*+ RULE*/` hint and without `/*+ RULE*/` hint

Querying `dba_users` with rule hint come with the same result:

```
SQL> explain plan for select /*+ RULE*/ * from dba_users;

Explained.

SQL>  SET LINESIZE 130
SET PAGESIZE 0
SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);SQL> SQL>
Plan hash value: 52995442

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name                    |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                         |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN OUTER                     |                         |
|   2 |   SORT JOIN                           |                         |
|   3 |    MERGE JOIN                         |                         |
|   4 |     SORT JOIN                         |                         |
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                     |                         |
```

Comment: Works as designed. That is what you get with the rule-based optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
alter session set statistics_level = all;
set serverout off
```

then run the query, then use `dbms_xplan.display_cursor` to display the plan for the last cursor execution:

```
select p.plan_table_output
from   table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor(null,null,'ALLSTATS LAST all +OUTLINE +PARTITION +HINT_REPORT +NOTE')) p;
```

You can run this more conveniently using a script such as [www.williamrobertson.net/documents/xplanx.html](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/xplanx.html):

```
SQL> select /*+ RULE*/ * from dba_users
  2
SQL>
SQL> @xplanx
SQL_ID  82hv76qsj59wm, child number 1
-------------------------------------
select /*+ RULE*/ * from dba_users

Plan hash value: 52995442

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                             | Name                    | Starts | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                      |                         |      1 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |     227 |       |       |          |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN OUTER                     |                         |      1 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |     227 |       |       |          |
|   2 |   SORT JOIN                           |                         |      1 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |     224 | 15360 | 15360 |14336  (0)|
|   3 |    MERGE JOIN                         |                         |      1 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |     224 |       |       |          |
|   4 |     SORT JOIN                         |                         |      1 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |     221 | 15360 | 15360 |14336  (0)|
|   5 |      NESTED LOOPS                     |                         |      1 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |     221 |       |       |          |
|   6 |       NESTED LOOPS OUTER              |                         |      1 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |     217 |       |       |          |
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS                   |                         |      1 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |     174 |       |       |          |
|   8 |         NESTED LOOPS                  |                         |      1 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |     131 |       |       |          |
|   9 |          NESTED LOOPS                 |                         |      1 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |      88 |       |       |          |
|  10 |           NESTED LOOPS                |                         |      1 |      9 |00:00:00.01 |       7 |       |       |          |
|  11 |            TABLE ACCESS FULL          | USER_ASTATUS_MAP        |      1 |      9 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 12 |            TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| PROFILE$                |      9 |      9 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 13 |             INDEX RANGE SCAN          | I_PROFILE               |      9 |    162 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 14 |           TABLE ACCESS FULL           | USER$                   |      9 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |      81 |       |       |          |
|  15 |          TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER         | TS$                     |     39 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |      43 |       |       |          |
|* 16 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN           | I_TS#                   |     39 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|  17 |         TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER          | TS$                     |     39 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |      43 |       |       |          |
|* 18 |          INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | I_TS#                   |     39 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|  19 |        TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER           | TS$                     |     39 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |      43 |       |       |          |
|* 20 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN             | I_TS#                   |     39 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 21 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID     | PROFILE$                |     39 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |       4 |       |       |          |
|* 22 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN               | I_PROFILE               |     39 |    702 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 23 |     SORT JOIN                         |                         |     39 |     39 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |  2048 |  2048 | 2048  (0)|
|  24 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                | PROFNAME$               |      1 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
|* 25 |   SORT JOIN                           |                         |     39 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |  2048 |  2048 | 2048  (0)|
|* 26 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | RESOURCE_GROUP_MAPPING$ |      1 |      2 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |       |       |          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Query Block Name / Object Alias (identified by operation id):
-------------------------------------------------------------

   1 - SEL$F79F3764
  11 - SEL$F79F3764 / M@SEL$4
  12 - SEL$F79F3764 / DP@SEL$4
  13 - SEL$F79F3764 / DP@SEL$4
  14 - SEL$F79F3764 / U@SEL$2
  15 - SEL$F79F3764 / TTS@SEL$4
  16 - SEL$F79F3764 / TTS@SEL$4
  17 - SEL$F79F3764 / DTS@SEL$4
  18 - SEL$F79F3764 / DTS@SEL$4
  19 - SEL$F79F3764 / LTTS@SEL$3
  20 - SEL$F79F3764 / LTTS@SEL$3
  21 - SEL$F79F3764 / PR@SEL$4
  22 - SEL$F79F3764 / PR@SEL$4
  24 - SEL$F79F3764 / P@SEL$4
  26 - SEL$F79F3764 / CGM@SEL$2

Outline Data
-------------

  /*+
      BEGIN_OUTLINE_DATA
      IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
      OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('19.1.0')
      DB_VERSION('19.1.0')
      RBO_OUTLINE
      OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$F79F3764")
      MERGE(@"SEL$49DCB01B" >"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$49DCB01B")
      MERGE(@"SEL$1BEB249F" >"SEL$D2E4DCB5")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$D2E4DCB5")
      ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$4")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1BEB249F")
      MERGE(@"SEL$1A566D0B" >"SEL$791DB105")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$4")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$791DB105")
      ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$F52A8B21")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$1A566D0B")
      ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$F52A8B21")
      ANSI_REARCH(@"SEL$3")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$2")
      OUTLINE(@"SEL$3")
      FULL(@"SEL$F79F3764" "M"@"SEL$4")
      INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$F79F3764" "DP"@"SEL$4" ("PROFILE$"."PROFILE#"))
      FULL(@"SEL$F79F3764" "U"@"SEL$2")
      INDEX(@"SEL$F79F3764" "TTS"@"SEL$4" "I_TS#")
      INDEX(@"SEL$F79F3764" "DTS"@"SEL$4" "I_TS#")
      INDEX(@"SEL$F79F3764" "LTTS"@"SEL$3" "I_TS#")
      INDEX_RS_ASC(@"SEL$F79F3764" "PR"@"SEL$4" ("PROFILE$"."PROFILE#"))
      FULL(@"SEL$F79F3764" "P"@"SEL$4")
      FULL(@"SEL$F79F3764" "CGM"@"SEL$2")
      LEADING(@"SEL$F79F3764" "M"@"SEL$4" "DP"@"SEL$4" "U"@"SEL$2" "TTS"@"SEL$4" "DTS"@"SEL$4" "LTTS"@"SEL$3" "PR"@"SEL$4" "P"@"SEL$4"
              "CGM"@"SEL$2")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$F79F3764" "DP"@"SEL$4")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$F79F3764" "U"@"SEL$2")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$F79F3764" "TTS"@"SEL$4")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$F79F3764" "DTS"@"SEL$4")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$F79F3764" "LTTS"@"SEL$3")
      USE_NL(@"SEL$F79F3764" "PR"@"SEL$4")
      USE_MERGE(@"SEL$F79F3764" "P"@"SEL$4")
      USE_MERGE(@"SEL$F79F3764" "CGM"@"SEL$2")
      END_OUTLINE_DATA
  */

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

  12 - filter(("DP"."RESOURCE#"=1 AND "DP"."TYPE#"=1))
  13 - access("DP"."PROFILE#"=0)
  14 - filter(("U"."TYPE#"=1 AND ("U"."ASTATUS"="M"."STATUS#" OR "U"."ASTATUS"="M"."STATUS#"+16-BITAND("M"."STATUS#",16))))
  16 - access("U"."TEMPTS#"="TTS"."TS#")
  18 - access("U"."DATATS#"="DTS"."TS#")
  20 - access("U"."SPARE9"="LTTS"."TS#")
  21 - filter(("PR"."RESOURCE#"=1 AND "PR"."TYPE#"=1))
  22 - access("U"."RESOURCE$"="PR"."PROFILE#")
  23 - access("U"."RESOURCE$"="P"."PROFILE#")
       filter("U"."RESOURCE$"="P"."PROFILE#")
  25 - access("CGM"."VALUE"="U"."NAME")
       filter("CGM"."VALUE"="U"."NAME")
  26 - filter(("CGM"."STATUS"='ACTIVE' AND "CGM"."ATTRIBUTE"='ORACLE_USER'))

Column Projection Information (identified by operation id):
-----------------------------------------------------------

   1 - "U"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128], "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32], "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."USER#"[NUMBER,22],
       "P"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128], "U"."PASSWORD"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."CTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."PTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."EXPTIME"[DATE,7],
       "U"."LTIME"[DATE,7], "PR"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."ASTATUS"[NUMBER,22], "U"."EXT_USERNAME"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."SPARE1"[NUMBER,22],
       "U"."SPARE3"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE4"[VARCHAR2,1000], "U"."SPARE6"[DATE,7], "TTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30], "DTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30],
       "LTTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30], "CGM"."CONSUMER_GROUP"[VARCHAR2,128]
   2 - (#keys=1) "U"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128], "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32], "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."USER#"[NUMBER,22],
       "P"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128], "U"."PASSWORD"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."CTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."PTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."EXPTIME"[DATE,7],
       "U"."LTIME"[DATE,7], "PR"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."ASTATUS"[NUMBER,22], "U"."EXT_USERNAME"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."SPARE1"[NUMBER,22],
       "U"."SPARE3"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE4"[VARCHAR2,1000], "U"."SPARE6"[DATE,7], "TTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30], "DTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30],
       "LTTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30]
   3 - "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32], "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."USER#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128],
       "U"."PASSWORD"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."CTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."PTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."EXPTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."LTIME"[DATE,7],
       "PR"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."ASTATUS"[NUMBER,22], "U"."EXT_USERNAME"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."SPARE1"[NUMBER,22],
       "U"."SPARE3"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE4"[VARCHAR2,1000], "U"."SPARE6"[DATE,7], "TTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30], "DTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30],
       "LTTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30], "P"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128]
   4 - (#keys=1) "U"."RESOURCE$"[NUMBER,22], "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32], "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."USER#"[NUMBER,22],
       "U"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128], "U"."PASSWORD"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."CTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."PTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."EXPTIME"[DATE,7],
       "U"."LTIME"[DATE,7], "PR"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."ASTATUS"[NUMBER,22], "U"."EXT_USERNAME"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."SPARE1"[NUMBER,22],
       "U"."SPARE3"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE4"[VARCHAR2,1000], "U"."SPARE6"[DATE,7], "TTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30], "DTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30],
       "LTTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30]
   5 - "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32], "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."USER#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128],
       "U"."PASSWORD"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."CTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."PTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."EXPTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."LTIME"[DATE,7],
       "U"."RESOURCE$"[NUMBER,22], "U"."ASTATUS"[NUMBER,22], "U"."EXT_USERNAME"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."SPARE1"[NUMBER,22],
       "U"."SPARE3"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE4"[VARCHAR2,1000], "U"."SPARE6"[DATE,7], "TTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30], "DTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30],
       "LTTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30], "PR"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22]
   6 - "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32], "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."USER#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128],
       "U"."PASSWORD"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."CTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."PTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."EXPTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."LTIME"[DATE,7],
       "U"."RESOURCE$"[NUMBER,22], "U"."ASTATUS"[NUMBER,22], "U"."EXT_USERNAME"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."SPARE1"[NUMBER,22],
       "U"."SPARE3"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE4"[VARCHAR2,1000], "U"."SPARE6"[DATE,7], "TTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30], "DTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30],
       "LTTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30]
   7 - "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32], "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."USER#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128],
       "U"."PASSWORD"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."CTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."PTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."EXPTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."LTIME"[DATE,7],
       "U"."RESOURCE$"[NUMBER,22], "U"."ASTATUS"[NUMBER,22], "U"."EXT_USERNAME"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."SPARE1"[NUMBER,22],
       "U"."SPARE3"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE4"[VARCHAR2,1000], "U"."SPARE6"[DATE,7], "U"."SPARE9"[NUMBER,22], "TTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30],
       "DTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30]
   8 - "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32], "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."USER#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128],
       "U"."PASSWORD"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."DATATS#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."CTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."PTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."EXPTIME"[DATE,7],
       "U"."LTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."RESOURCE$"[NUMBER,22], "U"."ASTATUS"[NUMBER,22], "U"."EXT_USERNAME"[VARCHAR2,4000],
       "U"."SPARE1"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE3"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE4"[VARCHAR2,1000], "U"."SPARE6"[DATE,7], "U"."SPARE9"[NUMBER,22],
       "TTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30]
   9 - "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32], "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."USER#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128],
       "U"."PASSWORD"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."DATATS#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."TEMPTS#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."CTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."PTIME"[DATE,7],
       "U"."EXPTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."LTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."RESOURCE$"[NUMBER,22], "U"."ASTATUS"[NUMBER,22], "U"."EXT_USERNAME"[VARCHAR2,4000],
       "U"."SPARE1"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE3"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE4"[VARCHAR2,1000], "U"."SPARE6"[DATE,7], "U"."SPARE9"[NUMBER,22]
  10 - "M"."STATUS#"[NUMBER,22], "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32], "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22]
  11 - "M"."STATUS#"[NUMBER,22], "M"."STATUS"[VARCHAR2,32]
  12 - "DP"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22]
  13 - "DP".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  14 - "U"."USER#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128], "U"."PASSWORD"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."DATATS#"[NUMBER,22],
       "U"."TEMPTS#"[NUMBER,22], "U"."CTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."PTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."EXPTIME"[DATE,7], "U"."LTIME"[DATE,7],
       "U"."RESOURCE$"[NUMBER,22], "U"."ASTATUS"[NUMBER,22], "U"."EXT_USERNAME"[VARCHAR2,4000], "U"."SPARE1"[NUMBER,22],
       "U"."SPARE3"[NUMBER,22], "U"."SPARE4"[VARCHAR2,1000], "U"."SPARE6"[DATE,7], "U"."SPARE9"[NUMBER,22]
  15 - "TTS".ROWID[ROWID,10], "TTS"."TS#"[NUMBER,22], "TTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30]
  16 - "TTS".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  17 - "DTS".ROWID[ROWID,10], "DTS"."TS#"[NUMBER,22], "DTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30]
  18 - "DTS".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  19 - "LTTS".ROWID[ROWID,10], "LTTS"."TS#"[NUMBER,22], "LTTS"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,30]
  20 - "LTTS".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  21 - "PR"."LIMIT#"[NUMBER,22]
  22 - "PR".ROWID[ROWID,10]
  23 - (#keys=1) "P"."PROFILE#"[NUMBER,22], "P"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128]
  24 - "P"."PROFILE#"[NUMBER,22], "P"."NAME"[VARCHAR2,128]
  25 - (#keys=1) "CGM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,128], "CGM"."CONSUMER_GROUP"[VARCHAR2,128]
  26 - "CGM"."VALUE"[VARCHAR2,128], "CGM"."CONSUMER_GROUP"[VARCHAR2,128]

Hint Report (identified by operation id / Query Block Name / Object Alias):
Total hints for statement: 1
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

   0 -  STATEMENT
           -  RULE

Note
-----
   - rule based optimizer used (consider using cbo)

timing for: Query execution time
Elapsed: 00:00:00.57


SQL>
```